# LazyList memory leak in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list, java-memory-leaks

I found out that LazyList generates memory leaks. When I scroll down to the bottom of the list memory usage by my app increases by ~3MB. After I scroll up and usage also increases by ~3MB. Memory usage increases all the time is scroll list. How to fix it?
[Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232438921) on Google IssueTracker

`P.S.` Sometimes memory usage drops down by 50-100mb. In my test project(code below) usage grows up to 150mb. In my other, more complex projects it grows up to 200-250mb. In a theory it can cause OutOfMemoryException.

Example:

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
                        item(span = { GridItemSpan(2) }) {
                            LargeTopAppBar(title = {
                                Text(text = "Explore new")
                            })
                        }
                        items(50) {
                            Box(modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(250.dp))
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running release version with r8 optimizations? If you can reproduce it with such a simple code, I suggest you [reporting it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128). Don't forget to mention used compose version, perfectly upload a sample project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Some thoughts after Google IO 2022:  
try to use "Key" parameter - items(count: Int, key: ((index: Int) -> Any)? = null)

Comment: @PylypDukhov yes, certainly, i use r8 optimizations. Also reported this bug

Comment: @brucemax unfortunately, keys didn't stop memory leaks.

Comment: LazyVerticalGrid is still unstable at this moment, you better use LazyColumn with Row inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230168389) and as of now still not resolved.

> In a theory it can cause OutOfMemoryException.

Not only in theory as we recently had to **downgrade** a production version of an app back to **Compose 1.1.1** due to this exact issue. As far as I know this is the only possible solution for now.

I guess we should stick to stable versions of Compose from now on.